# How do I set up this folder structure in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to switch from an Xcode project to a CMake-based project. (Xcode automated all the project config stuff). I have this project setup:

```
game/ (Includes the core utils used by the client and the server. Has libraries -llua, -lbullet, etc.)
| util.cpp
| CMakeLists.txt
game-client/ (The client. Has libraries -lglfw)
| window.cpp
| CMakeLists.txt
game-server/ (The server)
| server.cpp
| CMakeLists.txt
game-test/ (Tests source files in the game/ directory)
| util-tester.cpp
```

game-client/ and game-server/ both depend on game/. However, when I try to add `add_subdirectory(../tdgame)` to the game-client/CMakeLists.txt file, it tells me:

```
"game/" is not a subdirectory of "game-client/".  When specifying an
out-of-tree source a binary directory must be explicitly specified.
```

So how do I set this up? I've never used CMake before.

Comment: Why do you use multiple CMakeLists.txt files?

Comment: @KorelK one CMakeLists.txt per folder is best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would set such project:

`./CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(my_game)

add_subdirectory(game)
add_subdirectory(game-client)
add_subdirectory(game-server)
```

Note that it is crucial that sub-directories should be added in reverse dependency order. E.g. `game-server` depends on `game`, so it should be added after it.

`./game/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(Lua REQUIRED)

add_library(game utils.cpp)
target_include_directories(game PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(game PUBLIC ${LUA_LIBRARIES})
```

The `target_include_directories` and `target_link_libraries` are crucial here. When you use `PUBLIC` mode, you inform `cmake` that each target that depends on your library should also have those directories added to pre-processor search path and if it is an executable it should be linked also with your dependencies.

`./game-client/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(game-server main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(game-server PUBLIC game)
```

You need also let `cmake` know that your executable depends on your library.

Here is an example (the example source is in `/tmp/so/game`)

```
$ make VERBOSE=1 | grep main.cpp
[...]
cd /tmp/a/game-client && /usr/bin/c++   -I/tmp/so/game -I/usr/include/lua5.3   -o CMakeFiles/game-client.dir/main.cpp.o -c /tmp/so/game-client/main.cpp
/usr/bin/c++    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/game-client.dir/main.cpp.o  -o game-client ../game/libgame.a -llua5.3 -lm
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're running CMake from the `game-client` project, the `game` directory will be *outside* the source tree of the `game-client` project. So, as the error message explains, you must provide a binary directory for CMake to use for generated build files related to `game`:

```
add_subdirectory(../tdgame ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/game)
```

Perhaps a better approach would be to build all of these projects within the *same* CMake instance. Just add a top-level CMakeLists.txt file (as a sibling of the `game` folder), which calls `add_subdirectory()` for each of the sub-projects:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(MyGameProj)

add_subdirectory(game)
add_subdirectory(game-client)
add_subdirectory(game-server)
# Uncomment this if your 'game-test' directory also contains a CMakeLists.txt file.
#add_subdirectory(game-test)
```

Comment: How would I link the source files from game into game-client?

Comment: @cry0genic You haven't shown the contents of your CMake files so I cannot comment about specifically how... One way is: If your `game/CMakeLists.txt` file creates a library target (via `add_library(Game ...)` or similar), then you can simply link this library target to your game-client CMake target (e.g. `target_link_libraries(Game-client PRIVATE Game)`).